# Function evaluation in dplyr summarize

Tags: r, function, aggregate, tidyverse

I think I'm missing something fundamental about how R evaluates things.  Consider the following:

```
library("tidyverse")
dt0 <- tibble(x=1:10, y=11:20)
filter(dt0, 1==x)                          # Returns the first row
purrr::contains(list(1), 1)                # TRUE
filter(dt0, purrr::contains(list(1), x))   # Returns NO rows
```

I tried wrapping `contains` in a custom function (no change), and added a print statement to try to debug this, but it as near as I can tell, even when the value of `x` is 1 (class is still numeric), `contains(list(1), x)` returns `TRUE` outside of filter, but `FALSE` inside it.

1. Why?

Possibly related, I don't really understand how you can pass columns to functions like `unique` but ALSO to other functions (like my custom one).  (I understand that you can and do, but not how it's possible.)  My custom function behaved as though it was called multiple times, once for each value of x.  `unique`, though, would have to have *all* the values, yeah?

2. How can both `unique` and a single-argument function work on a column?

Comment: not sure the nature of purrr::contains, but `purrr::contains(list(1), dt0$x[1])` returns `FALSE`. despite `dt0$x[1]==1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the issue is coming down to the classes of the comparison.  Down in the source of `purrr::contains()` an `indentical()` is being called to compare `dt0$x` to `list[[i]]`.  The contents of `dt0$x` are integer while `1` is not.  So to fix this we can use `1L`.

```
> is.integer(1:10)
[1] TRUE
> is.integer(1)
[1] FALSE

> identical((1:10)[1], 1)
[1] FALSE
> identical((1:10)[1], 1L)
[1] TRUE
```

However the call to `filter(dt0, purrr::contains(list(1L), x))` will still return zero rows since the second argument is not iterated over in `purrr::contains()`.  So it is checking if the whole column `x` is contained in the `list(1)` (which is of course `FALSE`).  You'll have to manually iterate over the second arg if you want to use `purrr::contains` in this way.

I don't think the syntax is that elegant but if you want to stay in `purrr` you can use:

```
> filter(dt0, purrr::map_lgl(x,~purrr::contains(list(1L), .x)))
# A tibble: 1 × 2
      x     y
  <int> <int>
1     1    11
```

Comment: Hmm, ok.  I think what was really throwing me off was that (as far as I can tell) a lot of functions, say `f`, when given an array, will effectively return an array of `f(i)` for each value `i` of the array.  This made me think that `f` was actually getting called many times (and thus should have worked with contains), when in actuality (as far as I can tell) all functions acting on columns in a filter just get arrays passed to them.

Comment: its on a function by function basis if the `f(i)` behavior you referenced occurs.  a lot of functions in R are vectorized and so a lot of them do behave in that way, but others (like `identical()`) are not vectorized so its up to the user to do the iterating if desired.  you can also use `Vectorize()` in some cases like this (ex: `v_identical = Vectorize(identical, 'y'); v_identical(1,c(1,1))`)